# Using <div> instead of other tag types (<span>, <p>, etc)

Tags: html, css, html5

Is it considered bad style to always use `<div>` instead of using, say, `<span>`? I know that using specific tags like `span` better convey the purpose of the node, but is it actually frowned upon to always use `div` instead?

For example, if I were to have an inline style:

`<div class="hello">Hello, my name is <div class="name-div">John Doe</div></div>`

`<div class="hello">Hello, my name is <span class="name-span">John Doe</span></div>`

Where the `name-div` class would have `display: inline` set. Is either way considered fine or is there a commonly accepted preference?

Edit:

Here is an actual example so that maybe this won't be off-topic:

`<div class="online">You have been online for <span class="time">30</span> days.</div>`

Where the desired output is something like:

You have been online for **30** days.

(i.e. the 30 has some special styling).

In this case, is it really considered "bad" to use a `div` with `inline` styling rather than `span`? I feel that arguments can be made either way in that `span` is obviously more accurately describing the function of that node, but you could also say it's preferable to minimize the variety of tags for the sake of consistency across browsers (and choose not to use things like `em` or `strong` in lieu of special styling on a `div`).

Comment: Edited my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this question is actually off-topic since it doesn't contain real (or realistic) code, but example/placeholder code and text. In this case it's important because the choice whether to use `span` or `div` depends on the content (and context) of the text.

---

One way to think about it, is: Would it make sense, if you don't have your style sheet and only the browser default style sheet is applied.

Using a `div` it would look like this:

> Hello, my name is
>
> John Doe

and using a `span` it would be

> Hello, my name is John Doe

As mentioned above the choice whould depend on the content and context. Let's assume that is example text is an actually real live sample:

If this is the introduction sentence to a text of someone introducing themselves, then it makes sense to interpret it as a continuing sentence, thus you probably should use `span`.

However if the goal is to simulate a ["Hello, my name is ..." sticker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84bSH.jpg) where the name is separate from the rest of the text, then it could make sense to use a `div`.

---

Another thing you should keep in mind, that `div` and `span` are very generic elements and only should be used as a last resort. Instead one should strive to use specific elements than convey a meaning. For example, if this were a quote that some one said, then you should use a `blockquote` element instead of the outer `div`. And for the name use `em` or `strong` if you want to emphasize it, or just an `i`, which can be a suitable element for a name.

---

Regarding your edit:

> In this case, is it really considered "bad" to use a div with inline styling rather than span?

In this case it most certainly is. It's part of the surrounding sentence and not a new **div**ision.

> I feel that arguments can be made either way in that span is obviously more accurately describing the function of that node, but you could also say it's preferable to minimize the variety of tags for the sake of consistency across browsers (and choose not to use things like em or strong in lieu of special styling on a div).

Are you saying you are afraid there are browsers out there, that only know the `div` element and could be confused by `span`, or even more "exotic" elements such as `em`. To be frank, that is absurd. Any reasonable browser out there can handle any element name you throw at them, even if you made them up (within the limits of HTML/XML rules for element names).

The whole focus of HTML is semantic mark-up of documents.

Comment: Could the down voter comment on what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: _First off, this question is actually off-topic_ - knowingly answering an off-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

The `div` element, short for division, is a **block** element mostly used to group larger chunks of HTML, to create CSS-styled layouts.

On the other hand, the `span` element is an **inline** element, mostly used to group and stylize text/images. It makes it easy to apply custom styles without changing the general layout.

Also, a `div` element takes *all available width* while the `span` only takes *as much width as necessary*.

It is certainly not illegal (since HTML5) what you're doing, but to follow semantics I'd use `span` for what you are trying to achieve.